# Jquery : Hide/show multiple div with a single button on each div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide/show multiple div with a single button on each div  (the text button is changing)

Actually i have this :

```
<a id="btnHideShow">Hide</a>
<div id="divA"></div>


$( "#btnHideShow" ).click(function() {
    if ($.trim($("#btnHideShow").text()) === "Show") {
        $( "#divA" ).show( "fast" );
        $("#btnHideShow").text("Hide");
    } else {
        $( "#divA" ).hide( "fast" );
        $("#btnHideShow").text("Hide");        
    }
});
```

It's works for this single div, how can i do for multiple div like this :

```
<a id="btnHideShow">Hide</a>
<div id="divA"></div>

<a id="btnHideShow">Hide</a>
<div id="divB"></div>

<a id="btnHideShow">Hide</a>
<div id="divC"></div>

<a id="btnHideShow">Hide</a>
<div id="divD"></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to hide all of the (divA,divB,divC,divD) when any of btnHideShow clicked? you shouldn't use same name for id's

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can not refactor your HTML code, you can do it using [next](http://jqapi.com/#p=next) function of jQuery, which gets the next sibling.

```
$( "#btnHideShow" ).click(function() {
    var button = $(this),
        buttonSibling = button.next('div:first');

    if (button.text()) === "Show") {
        buttonSibling.show( "fast" );
        button.text("Hide");
    } else {
        buttonSibling.hide( "fast" );
        button.text("Show");        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is always going to be your Dom structure you can use the .next(), also change your ID's to classes

**HTML**

```
<a class="btnHideShow">Hide</a>

<div id="divA">test</div>
<a class="btnHideShow">Hide</a>

<div id="divB">test</div>
<a class="btnHideShow">Hide</a>

<div id="divC">test</div>
<a class="btnHideShow">Hide</a>

<div id="divD">test</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".btnHideShow").click(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) === "Show") {
        $(this).next().show("fast");
        $(this).text("Hide");
    } else {
        $(this).next().hide("fast");
        $(this).text("Show");
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sr6a65dv/)

Comment: Thx but only the text is changing, i have some element between the <a> and <div> balise

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not good to use same id for multiple elements on a single page, so replace  `<a id="btnHideShow">Hide</a>` with  `<a class="btnHideShow">Hide</a>`

And then try this:

```
<a class="btnHideShow">Hide</a>
<div id="divA">
sdfsdfsdafsad
</div>

<a class="btnHideShow">Hide</a>
<div id="divB">

sdfdsfsdafsda
</div>

<a class="btnHideShow">Hide</a>
<div id="divC">
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdafsd
</div>

<a class="btnHideShow">Hide</a>
<div id="divD">
sdfsdsafasfsda
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".btnHideShow" ).click(function() {
        $(this).next('div').toggle('slow');
     if($(this).html() == 'Hide'){
        $(this).html("Show");
    }else{
        $(this).html("Hide");
    }
    });
})
</script>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbd4mqqp/

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you only text is changing means..?

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to show/hide div just next to the a(anchor) tag.. AM I right..?

Comment: The text button switch in 'hide/show', but the div isn't hide. And between the <a> tag and <div> tag i have some <tr><td> tag

Comment: are you using the same html structure as you have written above

Comment: Give  a common class to all dives which you want to hide on anchor click

Answer (score 0):

This also works ...

(btw.: avoid multiple elements with the same id within the same document !)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
          $('a').click(function (event) {
             $(this).next().slideToggle( "fast");
             $(this).text($(this).text() === "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide");
          });
       });
    </script>
    <style>
      .container {
         margin-top : 10px;
      }
      a {
        background : lightgray;
        border : 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  <head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
       <a id="btnHideShowA">Hide</a>
       <div>This is DIV A</div>
     </div>

     <div class="container">
       <a id="btnHideShowB">Hide</a>
       <div>This is DIV B</div>
     </div>

     <div class="container">
       <a id="btnHideShowC">Hide</a>
       <div>This is DIV C</div>
     </div>

     <div class="container">
       <a id="btnHideShowD">Hide</a>
       <div>This is DIV D</div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```